# Get the start and end date by passing week number and year

Tags: postgresql, datetime

I am using **EXTRACT(WEEK from doc_date)**  to extract the week number from a given datetime.

Is it possible to extract the start and end date by passing week number and year from Postgres?

Comment: **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add an INTERVAL of X weeks to the first date of the year, and 6 more days to get the last date.

```
select '2017-01-01'::date + interval '3 week' as StartWeekDate,
        ('2017-01-01'::date + interval '3 week') + interval '6 day' as EndWeekDate;
```

A reduced version:

```
select '2017-01-01'::date + interval '3 week' as StartWeekDate,
        ('2017-01-01'::date + interval '3 week 6 day') as EndWeekDate;
```